# Runtime Error 6 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, excel, vba

When I tried executing the following code on Excel for Mac (OS X), I get a runtime error 6 -stack overflow when it gets to the portion of the code when it's dividing the two resulting numbers (Reward_Over_Risk). This happens even when I change the variable from As Single to As Double or even As Variant. Running the same code on a Windows 10 OS, however produces the required results.

Is there away for me to get this resolved?

The code in question is as below (Note, I've only posted a portion of the code as the runtime error happens at the "Reward_Over_Risk" line:

```
Sub Trading_Plan_Code()

Dim Support_Line As Currency
Dim ATR As Currency
Dim Target_Entry As Currency
Dim Profit_Target As Currency
Dim Stop_Loss As Currency
Dim Reward_Over_Risk As Single
Dim Reward_Number As Currency
Dim Risk_Number As Currency

If Worksheets(1).Range("E11").Value = "Long" Then

    Support_Line = Worksheets(1).Range("H11").Value
    ATR = Worksheets(1).Range("I11").Value
    Target_Entry = Worksheets(1).Range("J11").Value
    Profit_Target = Worksheets(1).Range("K11").Value

    Stop_Loss = Support_Line - ATR
    Reward_Number = Profit_Target - Target_Entry 

'At this point the result for the Reward_Number is 2.2

    Risk_Number = Target_Entry - Stop_Loss

'At this point the result for Risk_Number is 1.5

    Worksheets(1).Range("L11").Value = Stop_Loss

    Reward_Over_Risk = Reward_Number / Risk_Number

    Worksheets(1).Range("M11").Value = Reward_Over_Risk

End If

End Sub
```

Funny enough, when I replace the "Reward_Number" and "Risk_Number" with whole numbers 2 & 1, the code runs. However, when I add the decimal points 2.2 and 1.5 I get the run time error. Again, I do not get this issue running the same code on a windows machine.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: First, error 6 is "Overflow", not "Stack overflow". It appears that the internal casting method differs between Windows and OSX.  Note that you're making a narrowing cast when you assign from `Currency` to `Single` (`Currency` is a scaled `Double`).  I'd try making all of the types `Currency` to avoid the implicit cast entirely.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried changing all of the types to As Currency and the error still persists. I've even tried Changing all the variables to As Single and that still yields the error.

Comment: Give `Double` a shot (for all the variables) if you haven't already. Outside of that, my best suggestion is to file a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and suggestions. Looks like I might have to file the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem that you had had by running some VBA code at Excel 16 through my os x computer. Also, as in your case, I tried to run the code through windows and no problem appeared. As a solution, I found out that by not specifying the type of the variable (`Dim Risk_Number` instead of `Dim Risk_Number As Currency`) - so letting it be a variant - the problem disappeared. I hope it is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I've encountered this Overflow 6 issue with data types Single, Currency and Date (MS Office 365 on MAC) and suspect it was introduced with a recent software update.

I found a work-around.

The following excerpt from a Sub generates run-time Error '6' Overflow on the first assignment statement ( Pm(1)=5 ):

```
    Dim Pm(3) as Single

    Pm(1) = 5    '// <——— Generates Overflow 6
    Pm(2) = 20.5
    Pm(3) = 300.75
```

What I found that works (though I don't like it) is to preface the assignment statements with

On Error Resume Next

as follows:

```
    Dim Pm(3) as Single

    On Error Resume Next 
    Pm(1) = 5
    Pm(2) = 20.5
    Pm(3) = 300.75
```

For reasons unknown to me, all three array assignment statements execute just fine (as verified by outputting them with MsgBox) as if no error had occurred.

Comment: CORRECTION. My apologies! this fix works only some of the time. Ignoring the error doesn't always result in successful execution of the code.